# Web Application in Cloud, how to organise customizations and main releases with our client?

Tags: web-development, release-management, cloud

**Context :**

We have deployed a cloud solution ERP (Acumatica) for one of our client. 
There is only one dedicated Production server on the cloud hosting the app.
We have our own local server to develop and integrate the customizations our client asked us so far in the scope of the project.

Now, Our client would like to be able to do their own customizations but we can't (don't have time) to review them and check that they are not going to break the production environment.

In the initial contract we had to ensure the main Acumatica releases over time.
But obviously, we don't want to maintain the developments that our client may have done without our approval.

**Question :**

How can we organise this situation if we both publish customization? And hopefully, discharge our responsibility over the cloud application integrity.

I will see if I can add a censored contract to the question.

Also I was unsure where to post this, maybe there are some tricky legal issues that can't be answered here. If you have any other stack exchange site to recommend I would be happy to post there too.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the external team access to your dev environment and have them develop and test there.

This will give you a good practical solution to minimizing the 'merge conflicts' between the two sets of work.

I would guess that your contract doesn't cover the situation whereby the client is causing you to have extra work due to change they make during the development of your changes.

However, perhaps you could negotiate a charge for allowing them to use your dev environment and consultancy on changes which would cover your costs and mabey even be profitable for you

Comment: Well our development environment is actually on premise (not accessible externaly), but we could find out something. 
Anyway I agree that the extra work due to our client development should be charged. I just need to define the boundaries precisely to be covered.